# OpenGL: Clipping textures and its performance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, performance, opengl-es

Is it faster to render 2 moving (and tileable) background images (two 640*960 textures) or to clip them dynamically so that exactly 640*960 pixels of the screen are used and not more?

I am trying to achieve a moving background effect but do not know which of the two ways is faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't have any effect, because GPU performs clipping itself after the fragment stage.
Even more: it would be slower if you do that yourself.
This is true only if the size of your texture is slightly bigger then the screen. But if you're using some large map (for example 4096x4096) then you need to split it in several smaller tiles.